# Error CreateAppoiment Exchange Java

Tags: java, timezone, exchange-server, exchangewebservices

I am creating a task in outlook account with the following date:

```
startDate = 06/27/2015 13:00:00
endDate = 27/06/2015 15:00:00
```

And he put

```
TimeZone = America / Bogota
```

but on the agenda appears set me the task but with the following dates as having set another TimeZone:

```
startDate = 6/27/2015 8:00:00 
endDate = 27/06/2015 10:00:00
```

I could not configure the time zone.

Comment: You are using EWS Java API - correct?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use Windows time zone format.  So, try using "SA Pacific Standard Time".  And check out this [link](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc749073(v=ws.10).aspx) for a list of time zones.

Comment: In the client EWS API JAVA can't put the timezone "SA Pacific Standard Time", I put this and find right.


TimeZoneDefinition timezone=getTimeZone(service,"America/Bogota");
appointment.setStartTimeZone(timezone);
appointment.setEndTimeZone(timezone);



This work, and find TimeZone.name='Hora colombia', but dont have Transitions and Periods, and on the agenda set me task with other dates.


Help me, please!



I have the idea of adding five hours to date, and thus would remain with the date of Colombia . Not if you think good idea?